# Xcode 7.3 does not show up any downloadable iOS simulator

Tags: xcode

Just upgrade my Xcode from 7.2.1 to 7.3. Have no idea why. Do I have choices other than delete Xcode and reinstall again? (which I highly don't like).

BTW, the documentation tab is fine. Just a blank simulators.

Update: If I click "check and isntall now", it reports:

***Could not download and install OS X 10.11.4 Documentation. The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net” which could put your confidential information at risk.***

I checked cert on https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net, seems fine..

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem today. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066325/xcode-7-3-1-no-downloadable-simulator-runtimes. Although this is an older question... are there any solutions? :)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7.3 I found the following way to add older simulator versions.

1.) Choose "Window" from the menu bar

2.) Choose "Devices" from the drop down menu list

*Result: Devices window opens*

3.) Click the "+" icon in the lower left-hand corner of the window.

4.) Choose the Add Simulator option

*Result: You can add a simulator (and download older ones).*